# new battery for my toshiba laptop, rechargable Li-ion Battery Pack

Tags: laptop, battery

The instructions that came with the battery say to discharge battery to 2% then charge fully to 100%, how do I discharge the battery?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to let the battery inside the computer, and use it without plugging it to the socket until it reach 2%.

But normally, new Li-ion batteries only need to be charged at 100% before use, no need to discharge it like the old batteries that came from 2006 and downwards..

Furthermore, Windows will usually go into sleep mode or shut down itself around 5%, in order to avoid data loss from the computer suddenly shutting down. So I think you won't be able to reach 2%.

Answer (score 1):

Discharging the battery simply means draining it of power. You can just turn on your laptop (unplugged), and keep it running until the battery runs down to 2% (or until Windows shuts off to save power). Then you can charge it up.

To drain the battery faster, turn your screen brightness up all they way, make sure your wifi (and bluetooth if your laptop has it) are on, and play some video (or better yet a high end 3d game) for a few hours.

If you have to leave the computer, make sure to change the power settings to prevent it from sleeping.

I must say, though I'm not really sure how much benefit there actually is to doing this.

Answer (score 1):

With the battery in the laptop, leave the laptop on until the batter drains to 2%. In order to reach 2% you will need to adjust to power settings as follows:

First adjust sleep settings by going to:
`Start > Search > Power Options > Change Plan Settings > Put the computer to sleep`
and change it to `Never`.

Next change the power settings by going to:
`Start > Search > Power Options > Change Plan Settings > Change Advanced Power Settings > Battery > Critical battery level` and change it to `2%`.

However, I never did this before, because technology advances so fast you'll need a new laptop long before your battery dies.

Moreover, Lithium Ion (Li-ion) batteries do not need to be fully discharged. This instruction is based off old instructions for old battery technology which if you did not do this the battery lasted a shorter time. These instructions no longer apply because Lithium Ion batteries are not subject to this issue.